# Too much recursion - radio button - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2

I have a dynamic form and in that many fields I want to be autocalculated when user goes on with the form. In the form I have 2 radio button `mrp` and `rate`. By default mrp is selected. If user doesn't change the default button selected, the value `totalCst` will be calculated as `qty*mrp*cstpercent` of all the rows.
If user selects `rate` radiobutton the value will be calculated as `qty*rate*cstpercent` of all the rows. I'll add the onchange event later. First  I want to get the value totalCst calculated on mrp only or rate whichever is selected.

Radio Button code -

```
<div class="form-group pull-right">
                    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="taxon" id="mrp"  value="mrp" checked="checked">MRP</label>
                    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="taxon" id="rate" value="rate">Rate</label>
                </div>
```

JS

```
<?php
/* start getting the total amount */
$this->registerJs('
    function getSum() {
        var sum = 0;
        var totalDiscount = 0;
        var totalMrp = 0;
        var totalCst = 0;
        var totalWbst = 0;
        var totalCstonamount = 0;
        var totalWbstonamount = 0;
        var totalCstonmrp = 0;
        var totalWbstonmrp = 0;

        var cstperValue = $(".cstPercent").val();
        var wbstperValue = $(".wbstPercent").val();
        var selectedValue = $("input[name=taxon]:checked").val();
        alert(selectedValue);

        var items = $(".item");
        items.each(function (index, elem) {
            var qtyValue = $(elem).find(".qty").val();
            var rateValue = $(elem).find(".rate").val();
            var discValue = $(elem).find(".disc").val();
            var mrpValue = $(elem).find(".mrp").val();
            var freeValue = $(elem).find(".free").val();


            sum = (parseFloat(sum) + (parseFloat(qtyValue) * parseFloat(rateValue))).toFixed(2);
            totalDiscount = (parseFloat(totalDiscount) + ((parseFloat(qtyValue) * parseFloat(rateValue) * parseFloat(discValue))/100)).toFixed(2);
            totalMrp = (parseFloat(totalMrp) + ((parseFloat(qtyValue) + parseFloat(freeValue)) * parseFloat(mrpValue))).toFixed(2);
            totalCstonamount = (parseFloat(totalCst) + ((parseFloat(qtyValue) * parseFloat(rateValue)) * parseFloat(cstperValue))/100).toFixed(2);
            totalWbstonamount = (parseFloat(totalWbst) + ((parseFloat(qtyValue) * parseFloat(rateValue)) * parseFloat(wbstperValue))/100).toFixed(2);
            totalCstonmrp = (parseFloat(totalCst) + (((parseFloat(qtyValue) + parseFloat(freeValue)) * parseFloat(mrpValue)) * parseFloat(cstperValue))/100).toFixed(2);
            totalWbstonmrp = (parseFloat(totalWbst) + (((parseFloat(qtyValue) + parseFloat(freeValue)) * parseFloat(mrpValue)) * parseFloat(wbstperValue))/100).toFixed(2);



        });

       if(isNaN(sum) || sum.length == 0) {
           sum = 0;
       }
       if(isNaN(totalDiscount) || totalDiscount.length == 0) {
           totalDiscount = 0;
       }
       if(isNaN(totalMrp) || totalMrp.length == 0) {
           totalMrp = 0;
       }
       if(isNaN(totalCstonamount) || totalCstonamount.length == 0) {
           totalCstonamount = 0;
       }
       if(isNaN(totalWbstonamount) || totalWbstonamount.length == 0) {
           totalWbstonamount = 0;
       }
       if(isNaN(totalCstonmrp) || totalCstonmrp.length == 0) {
           totalCstonmrp = 0;
       }
       if(isNaN(totalWbstonmrp) || totalWbstonmrp.length == 0) {
           totalWbstonmrp = 0;
       }



       $(".sum").val(sum);
       $(".totalDiscount").val(totalDiscount);
       $(".totalMrp").val(totalMrp);


       if (selectedValue == "mrp") {
            getSum();
           $(".totalCst").val(totalCstonmrp);
        }
        else if (selectedValue == "rate") {
            getSum();
           $(".totalCst").val(totalCstonamount);
        }

    }

    $(".container-items").on("change", function() {
        getSum();
    });

    $(".cstPercent").on("change", function() {
        getSum();
    });

    $(".wbstPercent").on("change", function() {
        getSum();
    });

    jQuery(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("afterDelete", function(e) {
        getSum();
    }); 

');
/*end getting the total amount */
?>
```

I'm getting the value selected in alert but too many popup and getting error - 
Too much recursion
[image]

**Updated JS**

```
<?php
/* start getting the total amount */
$this->registerJs('
    var totalCstonamount = 0;
    var totalWbstonamount = 0;
    var totalCstonmrp = 0;
    var totalWbstonmrp = 0;

    function getSum() {
        var sum = 0;
        var totalDiscount = 0;
        var totalMrp = 0;
        var totalCst = 0;
        var totalWbst = 0;
        // var totalCstonamount = 0;
        // var totalWbstonamount = 0;
        // var totalCstonmrp = 0;
        // var totalWbstonmrp = 0;

        var cstperValue = $(".cstPercent").val();
        var wbstperValue = $(".wbstPercent").val();
        //var selectedValue = $("input[name=taxon]:checked").val();
        //alert(selectedValue);

        var items = $(".item");
        items.each(function (index, elem) {
            var qtyValue = $(elem).find(".qty").val();
            var rateValue = $(elem).find(".rate").val();
            var discValue = $(elem).find(".disc").val();
            var mrpValue = $(elem).find(".mrp").val();
            var freeValue = $(elem).find(".free").val();


            sum = (parseFloat(sum) + (parseFloat(qtyValue) * parseFloat(rateValue))).toFixed(2);
            totalDiscount = (parseFloat(totalDiscount) + ((parseFloat(qtyValue) * parseFloat(rateValue) * parseFloat(discValue))/100)).toFixed(2);
            totalMrp = (parseFloat(totalMrp) + ((parseFloat(qtyValue) + parseFloat(freeValue)) * parseFloat(mrpValue))).toFixed(2);
            totalCstonamount = (parseFloat(totalCst) + ((parseFloat(qtyValue) * parseFloat(rateValue)) * parseFloat(cstperValue))/100).toFixed(2);
            totalWbstonamount = (parseFloat(totalWbst) + ((parseFloat(qtyValue) * parseFloat(rateValue)) * parseFloat(wbstperValue))/100).toFixed(2);
            totalCstonmrp = (parseFloat(totalCst) + (((parseFloat(qtyValue) + parseFloat(freeValue)) * parseFloat(mrpValue)) * parseFloat(cstperValue))/100).toFixed(2);
            totalWbstonmrp = (parseFloat(totalWbst) + (((parseFloat(qtyValue) + parseFloat(freeValue)) * parseFloat(mrpValue)) * parseFloat(wbstperValue))/100).toFixed(2);



        });

       if(isNaN(sum) || sum.length == 0) {
           sum = 0;
       }
       if(isNaN(totalDiscount) || totalDiscount.length == 0) {
           totalDiscount = 0;
       }
       if(isNaN(totalMrp) || totalMrp.length == 0) {
           totalMrp = 0;
       }
       if(isNaN(totalCstonamount) || totalCstonamount.length == 0) {
           totalCstonamount = 0;
       }
       if(isNaN(totalWbstonamount) || totalWbstonamount.length == 0) {
           totalWbstonamount = 0;
       }
       if(isNaN(totalCstonmrp) || totalCstonmrp.length == 0) {
           totalCstonmrp = 0;
       }
       if(isNaN(totalWbstonmrp) || totalWbstonmrp.length == 0) {
           totalWbstonmrp = 0;
       }



       $(".sum").val(sum);
       $(".totalDiscount").val(totalDiscount);
       $(".totalMrp").val(totalMrp);


       // if (selectedValue == "mrp") {
       //      getSum();
       //     $(".totalCst").val(totalCstonmrp);
       //  }
       //  else if (selectedValue == "rate") {
       //      getSum();
       //     $(".totalCst").val(totalCstonamount);
       //  }

    }

    function getSumonclick(){

    }

    $(".container-items").on("change", function() {
        getSum();
    });

    $(".cstPercent").on("change", function() {
        getSum();
    });

    $(".wbstPercent").on("change", function() {
        getSum();
    });

    getSum();
    var selectedValue = $("input[name=taxon]:checked").val();
    // var totalCstonamount = 200;
    // var totalWbstonamount = 0;
    // var totalCstonmrp = 100;
    // var totalWbstonmrp = 0;

    if (selectedValue == "mrp") {
           getSum();              
               if(isNaN(totalCstonmrp) || totalCstonmrp.length == 0) {
                   totalCstonmrp = 0;
               }
           $(".totalCst").val(totalCstonmrp);
        }
        else if (selectedValue == "rate") {
            getSum();
                if(isNaN(totalCstonamount) || totalCstonamount.length == 0) {
                totalCstonamount = 0;
               }
           $(".totalCst").val(totalCstonamount);
        }

    jQuery(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("afterDelete", function(e) {
        getSum();
    }); 



');
/*end getting the total amount */
?>
```

As per my understanding, Now the issue turns out to be to get the calculated values from inside of getSum function to outside of it.

Comment: Since `$("input[name=taxon]:checked").val();` , AKA `selectedValue`, is not changing between `getSum()` calls, it either stays "mrp" or "rate".

Comment: If it stays as "mrp" or "rate" also, it should be detected in the if..else.. statement and allow getSum to calculate.. Please let me know if I'm wrong. Also, how to fix it.

Comment: If those values stay the same and continually pass the condition, there will be too much recursion. `getSum()` keeps calling itself. There has to be a breaking point. Set a higher scoped variable or something.

Comment: Oh. How to fix it?

Comment: Try putting `selectedValue` outside of your `getSum()` scope *(above the function)* then do like `selectedValue = undefined;` after calling `getSum()` under your conditions. Then it won't be "mrp" or "rate" and `getSum()` won't keep calling itself.

Comment: You mean the whole line var selectedValue = $("input[name=taxon]:checked").val(); outside getSum().. Right?

Comment: I've updated the jquery part and added it in the question. Please let me know if this what you were asking about.

Answer (score 0):

> First I want to get the value totalCst calculated on mrp only or rate
>   whichever is selected.

You can use the **ternary operator** here, rather than `if... else...`:

```
var factor = (factorMrp.checked ? 'mrp' : 'rate');
```

**Working Example:**

```js
var factors = document.getElementById('factors');
var factorMrp = document.getElementById('mrp');
var factorRate = document.getElementById('rate');
var paragraph = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];

factorMrp.checked = true;

function checkFactor() {
var factor = (factorMrp.checked ? 'mrp' : 'rate');
paragraph.textContent = 'The value totalCst will be calculated as qty * ' + factor + ' * cstpercent of all the rows.';
}

factors.addEventListener('change',checkFactor,false);
window.addEventListener('load',checkFactor,false);
```

```css
fieldset {
display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<form>
<fieldset id="factors">
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="taxon" id="mrp"  value="mrp" checked="checked">MRP</label>
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="taxon" id="rate" value="rate">Rate</label>
</fieldset>
</form>

<p></p>
```